# Why can't I login on the remote computer without a password after using SSH-KEYGEN command?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have two computers. From the first I created the account `admin1` with password `admin1`. Then I logged in as a root user and used the `ssh-keygen -t rsa` command. I did not give a password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> three times.

[image]

In the next step I typed `ssh root@remoteuser's ip`. Then I logged out and tried to connect to the second computerm but it asked for the password again...

Next, I used the commands:

```
#useradd admin1
#passwd admin1
#ssh-keygen -t rsa
#ssh root@remoteuser's ip
```

Why does it ask for the password again?

Comment: U need to copy id **ssh-copy-id root@userip**

Comment: _What do you mean?_

Comment: Next time restate ur question! And add picture with error please.

Comment: Elaborate what you want to do in your question.  Does `admin1` account have anything to do with your question after all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this again:

    #useradd admin1
    #passwd admin1
    #ssh-keygen -t rsa
    **#ssh-copy-id root@remoteuserip**
    #exit
```

then type:

```
    #ssh root@remoteuser's ip
```

Comment: If you wonder what `ssh-copy-id` does: It appends the public key (id_rsa.pub) to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the destination side. The public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the destination needs to match the private key in `ssh/id_rsa` for remote login to work (and there are some restrictions on access rights of the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file). If you ever think it should work, but doesn't, this is the place to check.

Answer (score 11):

Generating a key doesn't automatically allow you to log in with it to remote machines.  You need to copy the corresponding public key to the machines you want to access, like this:

```
ssh-copy-id user@remote.machi.ne
```

This operation will ask you for `user`'s password on `remote.machi.ne`, but after that you'll be able to `ssh` with your key:

```
ssh -l user remote.machi.ne
```

If you didn't set a password for your key, `ssh` will no longer ask you to enter one.

On a side note: it looks like you had an old `ssh` key that you just overwrote.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your scenario is the following. You have computer1(runs sshd service) and computer2(has the keys) and you need to use the keys to connect **from** computer2 **to** computer1.

In computer 2, you will do the `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and you will generate two keys(one public the one which ends to .pub and the private one). In order to use these keys in your ssh connection from computer2 to computer1 then you have to copy the `.pub` file to computer1. For the first time you will have to use your password, and after you copy the public key to the remote machine your next sessions will be passwordless(if you leave empty the password in the key generation). Be noted that the user who runs `ssh-keygen` will have the keys under his home directory in ~/.ssh unless in you change the path and that specific user will have read access to the keys so they can be used.

There are two methods to copy the .pub file to the remote machine, 
**1st - Automatic**) using `ssh-copy-id -i ~/id_rsa.pub username@computer1`
**2nd - Manually**) `ssh` to computer1 and create a directory .ssh in the user's home directory you want to ssh passwordless, and then create a file in .ssh named as `authorized_keys` and copy-paste the content from computer2.(you can add more keys appending new lines)